# What is bundled into vendor.bundle.js?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

The angular-cli is producing `vendor.bundle.js` when executing a build.

What are the rules of what is going to be considered packed under `vendor.bundle.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think any modules imported into the app.module.ts file will show up in the vendor bundle.

Example app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`vendors.bundle.js` bundles every code imported by your app module: this includes local imports like components and services, but also third-party libs like lodash. It basically contains everything, so it's more interesting to see what's *not* in this file, mainly:

- `inline.bundle.js`: webpack loader
- `scripts.build.js`: all the scripts declared in `angular-cli`'s `scripts` entry
- `polyfills.bundle.js`: polyfills declared in `polyfills.bundle.js`

More details [here](https://upgradetoangular.com/angular-news/the-angular-cli-is-a-great-way-to-build-your-angular-app-but-what-it-does-can-be-a-mystery-what-are-those-files-it-generates/)

Answer (score 0):

It has also got to do with packaging. Meaning what's inside your `package.json` file, located generally in the root folder of your application. Which then makes it possible to load those found within `@NgModule({...})` that Kevin posted.